# Facebook login in ASP.Net Core Identity for mobile API and use Facebook app to login

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

We're developing a mobile application on iOS and Android with our own back-end and API server using ASP.Net Core with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.

We need to allow users to login with Facebook as optional for default phone/email account.

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1) from Microsoft docs. But this method seems to require the user to login with browser. By creating a controller from the server to redirect user to Facebook login dialog using framework provided `Challenge()` method.

```cs
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        ...

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("External/Facebook}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalFacebook(string myparam)
        {
            // myparam validation

            var scheme = await authService.GetExternalProviderSchemeAsync("Facebook");
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalFacebookCallback), null, new { myparam }, Request.Scheme);
            var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(scheme.Name, redirectUrl);

            return Challenge(properties, scheme.Name );
        }
    }
```

Then in `ExternalFacebookCallback` I only need to verify that the user is authenticated with Facebook and then login/create user to my system, providing my own access token.

The problem for this method is, as mentioned, it seems to require user to be logged in with browser, not the Facebook app. And my user base seems to use Facebook app and don't seem to be happy to log in again in the browser.

We currently use a method that I don't feel happy to use. We let the client use Facebook SDK for iOS and Android to get `access_token` and post the token to server. The server then use the token with Facebook to verify and get user information.

Is there a better way to do this?
Or the current method is already OK? 
Thank you.

Comment: Explain _why_ you’re “not happy” with how things are currently working …?

Comment: I think Facebook access token shoild be used to communicate with Facebook API than to use as a temporary/secondhand (don't know what word to use, sorry for my bad English) for the API server just to use it only once to get user information.

Comment: Getting the user information once _is_ an API call already.

Comment: Even Facebook’s own guidelines say it is fine to send a token from the client to the server, to verify the user’s identity by then making an API call from the server side, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm

Comment: Maybe i was wrong. But what I'm trying to tell was that I think the token was requested by client as issued for the client. I think it's for the client to communicate with Facebook and should not be used by the server.

Comment: These tokens are not bound to any specific platform. Plus, trying to verify an email address client-side makes little sense to begin with - the user could still interfere with that at any point, and thereby make you accept an email as “verified”, that actually isn’t. Only when your server directly communicates with the API, you can be sure the data was not manipulated. Anything that your _client_ sends to your server, has to be considered potentially tainted.

Comment: Thank you. I should be more confident with the current method now.